# How to import data from Excel file into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have records in Excel file. The columns are really custom and nothing to do with any database column but I want to import this data from Excel file into MySQL data. Is there any tool in MySQL by which I can map Excel columns to MySQL table columns and import the required data from excel file to MySQL

Comment: You can try PHPMyAdmin

Comment: I am not much familiar with PHP is it tool?

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial, it should help you with what you need

[phpMyAdmin – Import Excel CSV into table](http://richardcarterorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/phpmyadmin-import-excel-csv-into-table/)

Answer (score 0):

After 6 years of this Question - answer session,

I found a better solution from CSV format to import data into sql file.

Convert Excel file into Open Office Spread Sheet and Use Import option of phpMyAdmin

It gave following advantages

No data truncated 
No limitation of length of file 
Automatically upgraded SQL file structure to data format